# Multiple JSON objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, load

Hoping someone can answer this one... Is it possible to load multiple JSON files using a single jQuery.ajax(); call? or would I need to create a call for each file?

Your friendly neighbourhood,
Smccullough

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you'll have to make multiple calls or concatenate the files at the server.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery.ajax() does one http request at a time.

You could wrap it in a jquery function for loading the files.
Pseudo-ish code:

```
jquery.fn = function loadFiles(data){
  $.ajax({
    url: data.file,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: callback
    ... and so on
  });

}
```

somewhere else in your code:

```
$(this).loadFiles({file:'file-one.ext'});
$(this).loadFiles({file:'file-two.ext'});
```

Comment: jQuery provides the getJSON() method for this purpose. No need to wrap ajax() again. — http://docs.jquery.com/Getjson